# Use CSS to remove the space between images

Tags: html, css

Given:

```
<img src="..."/>
<img src="..."/>
```

The result is two images with a single space between them. It seems that the normal behavior is to show any number of spaces, newlines, and tabs as a single white space. I know I can do the following:

```
<img src="..."/><img src="..."/>
```

OR

```
<img src="..."/><!--
--><img src="..."/>
```

OR

```
<img src="..."/
><img src="..."/>
```

Or any number of other hacks. Is there a way to remove that whitespace with CSS? e.g.

```
<div class="nospace">
    <img src="..."/>
    <img src="..."/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Make them `display: block` in your CSS.

Comment: Better yet, `float: left` them as they need to be next to one another. Added benefit of making `<img>`s `display: block` is that mysterious bottom margin disappears as well.

Comment: With `float:left` works like a charm

Comment: For a bit more information about "Images, Tables, and Mysterious Gaps", see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps

Comment: If using `float: left`, also worth adding `clear: both` to a container element below your images to avoid funky overlapping layouts and the likes.

Comment: Using floats is like opening a Pandora's box. A can full or worms. The best solution is what @daniel-a-white offered: display them as blocks

Answer (score 88):

An easy way that is compatible pretty much everywhere is to set `font-size: 0` on the container, provided you don't have any descendent text nodes you need to style (though it is trivial to override this where needed).

```
.nospace {
   font-size: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LyFAb/).

You could also change from the default `display: inline` into `block` or `inline-block`. Be sure to use the [workarounds required](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) for <= IE7 (and possibly ancient Firefoxes) for `inline-block` to work.

Comment: That is clever. My only concern would be if I needed text in the `div` too. I suppose that is what `span` is for.

Comment: @steveo225: Yeah, that is a potential problem. Making the elements block level is probably best if it suits your requirements.

Comment: I ended up using this because I had a few `img` tags that were lined up and horizontally centred. `float:left;` aligned them all left;

Comment: Everybody else said set margin=0 and border=0 which didn't work.
Setting font-size=0 FINALLY resolved my problem. Thank you!!!

Comment: For my case I needed to set `line-height: 0;` instead of `font-size: 0;`.

Comment: The only answer works for me!

Answer (score 14):

The best solution I've found for this is to contain them in a parent div, and give that div a font-size of 0.

Answer (score 12):

I prefer do like this

```
img { float: left; }
```

to remove the space between images

Answer (score 10):

I found that the only option that worked for me was

```
font-size:0;
```

I was also using `overflow` and `white-space: nowrap; 
float: left;` seems to mess things up

Comment: Why does this get upvoted? Same answer has been given by alex 5 years earlier.

Comment: @jpoppe Stack Overflow prioritizes posts/answers that were more recently modified/edited. If you compare with alex's answer below, you'll noticed only this answer has been modified, but alex's has not.