# Extra space when input and button are next to each other

Tags: html, css

I can't figure this out for the life of me. Why is there an extra pixel at the top of the button? Also why is there extra white space to the left of it? All I am trying to do is have the input and the button next to each other looking connected.

Is this possible?

```css
html{
  background: green;
}
form {
  height: 40px;

  input {
    height: 30px;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 400px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 0;
    background: gray;
  }

  button {
    background: #6699FF;
    height: 40px;
    width: 60px;
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/Tp7TTNO.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-origin: content-box;
    padding: 7px;
    border: 0;
    color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="Term" class="saearch-input" placeholder="Search more than 3800 summaries">
  <button type="submit" class="">Search</button>
</form>
```

If you can't explain it either but know how I can achieve this another way, I'll accept it as an answer as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641678/use-css-to-remove-the-space-between-images

Comment: the upper links doesn't deal with input tag but it's the same issue and the fixes will all work here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space is there because a line jump (return) is considered a white space. To avoid this you can:

1. Put the `input` and `button` tags right next to each other (harder to read your code)
2. Use the "comment hack" where you'd write your code with a `<!--` right after the `<input>` and `-->` right before the `<button>`.
3. Use `display: flex` on your form to avoid the whitespace being rendered.

For your button positioning issue, it's related to the alignment on the baseline. `vertical-align: bottom;` on your button will fix this.

[See the solution on this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsxxwdgh/)

Comment: You sir, just saved me from going bald. Thank you. I actually knew about the character return problem, but completely all forgot about it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Bojan Happy to help! I've lost count how many times I've run into this kind of situation before. If you don't mind marking the answer as accepted, people who run into this later on can easily find the solution. ;)

Answer (score -2):

You need to change the position of the button:

```
position: absolute;
top : 8px;
```

This is the complete css code:

```
html{
background: green;
}
form {
  height: 40px;

  input {
    height: 30px;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 400px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 0;
    background: gray;
  }

  button {
    position: absolute;
    top : 8px;
    background: #6699FF;
    height: 40px;
    width: 60px;
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/Tp7TTNO.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-origin: content-box;
    padding: 7px;
    border: 0;
    color: transparent;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a hacky solution and won't work if OP changes the height of his elements.